# Convert a list of strings to numeric vector to calculate hamming distance

Tags: python

I have a list of unique words. I have to calculate the hamming distance between two list of strings. Suppose the list of strings are:

```
a = ['a' , 'b', 'c' ]
b = ['b' , 'a', 'd' ]
```

And let the unique words list be:

```
u = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I need to create two lists from `a` and `b` that will be of the same length as `u`. Suppose the lists are `va` and `vb`. Each element of `va` and `vb` will either be `0` or `1`. It will be `1` if corresponding element of `u` exists in `a` or `b` and `0` otherwise. For example,

```
va = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
vb = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I will then calculate the hamming distance between `va` and `vb` using the sklearn's pairwise distance metric. What is the most efficient way to calculate `va` and `vb` from `a`, `b` and `u`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a list comprehension is faster then using a `list(map(..))` combo:

```
a = ['a' , 'b', 'c' ]
b = ['b' , 'a', 'd' ]

u = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

sa=set(a)
sb=set(b)

va = [1 if x in sa else 0 for x in u]
vb = [1 if x in sb else 0 for x in u]

print(va)
print(vb)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Let's measure:

```
from timeit import timeit

print("map", timeit( lambda: list(map(lambda x: 1 if x in sa else 0, u)) )) 
print("list-comp", timeit( lambda: [1 if x in sa else 0 for x in u]))
```

to see that

```
map 41.271170677
list-comp 17.18380836300000  ( about 42% of the time map uses)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sa=set(a)
sb=set(b)    
va=list(map(lambda x: 1 if x in sa else 0, u))
vb=list(map(lambda x: 1 if x in sb else 0, u))

>>> print(va)
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
>>> print(vb)
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Is ``1 if x in a else 0`` of ``O(len(a))`` ?

Comment: Could you tell me the time complexity of this approach?

Comment: I think it's O(len(u)) as all u elements must be checked

Comment: Changed to set, as checking if item is in set is way faster than checking in list

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following listcomp:

```
a = ['a' , 'b', 'c' ]
u = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

a = set(a)
[int(i in a) for i in u]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```